# RSQLite dbWriteTable not working on large data

Tags: r, rmysql, rpostgresql, rsqlite, r-dbi

Here is my code, where I am trying to write a data from R to SQLite database file.

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "data.sqlite")

### Read the file you want to load to the SQLite database

data <- read_rds("data.rds")

dbSafeNames = function(names) {
  names = gsub('[^a-z0-9]+','_',tolower(names))
  names = make.names(names, unique=TRUE, allow_=TRUE)
  names = gsub('.','_',names, fixed=TRUE)
  names
}

colnames(data) = dbSafeNames(colnames(data))

### Load the dataset to the SQLite database

dbWriteTable(conn=con, name="data", value= data, row.names=FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

While writing the 80GB data, I see the size of the data.sqlite increasing upto 45GB and then it stops and throws the following error.

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : disk I/O error
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  no such savepoint: dbWriteTable
```

What is the fix and what should I do? If it's only with RSQLite, please suggest the most robust database creation method like RMySQL, RPostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: Issue can be your OS environment. Are you writing to thumb drive, network drive, etc.? Please give background and provide CPU details. But wow! 80GB of data? Since SQLite is a file-level DBMS, might as well stick with R's .rds file format.

Comment: Here are the details: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. Processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5570 @2.93GHz (2 processors). 64-bit OS. 144-GB RAM.

Comment: Do you have enough space on your drive, is it intact? The `disk I/O error` looks troublesome.

Comment: Space is few TBs. It's a server I connect through remote desktop, so the place I save my data.sqlite file may not be intact. What's a solution in that case.

Comment: @Geet: The location where you save our data file is important. Is it a network drive, or perhaps even a directory on your local computer connected through Remote Desktop? You could try saving to a local drive on the server.

Comment: Yes, it is a computer connected through the remote desktop. I will try what you have suggested.